# PowerPc applications are no longer supported

Tags: macos

I'm trying to install an application on my MacBook but I got this message error :

> You can't open the application .mpkg because PowerPc applications are
>   no longer supported.

I tried to this commande in Terminal: `sudo installer -package /Users/Mahmoud/Desktop/sagem -target /`

but I got this message :

> installer: Error the package path specified was invalid:
>   '/Users/Mahmoud/Desktop/sagem'.

the file which I want to install is located on the desktop and when I drag and drop it into terminal this is the path I got :

> /Users/Mahmoud/Desktop/sagem

the version of os i'm running is 10.7

Comment: Your only solution is a Virtual Machine with OS X 10.6.  Your current operating system does not support Power PC applications.

Answer (score 6):

The application you are trying to run is compiled for the PPC CPU found in older Apple computers. You need to find a newer version of the application that is built for x86 CPU:s

[10.7 Lion drops support for PowerPC applications](http://9to5mac.com/2011/02/26/10-7-lion-drops-support-for-powerpc-applications/)

Comment: the only version of the software I want to install is this i got now

Comment: +1 for being the only real fix. People have had 5+ years to find alternatives for their PowerPC apps, they've been living on borrowed time for a while now and support had to end at some point.

Comment: If you really can't live without that application, then you need to step back to OS X 10.6 so you get the "Rosetta" engine back, just as said in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=PowerPc+applications+are+no+longer+supported

Since OS X 10.7, Apple has cancelled the support for Power PC applications (coming from the older Processor architecture in G4 macs and before). Until OS 10.6 there was the "Rosetta" Engine which allowed using PowerPC apps.

You'll find more information about that in this blog post:
http://www.cultofmac.com/103458/os-x-lion-kills-rosetta-powerpc-support-heres-what-to-do-about-it/

Comment: yes .. but when I googled about it I found that there is a way to install those applications by trying this commande : sudo installer -package /Users/Mahmoud/Desktop/sagem -target /

Comment: @AimadMajdou if the PowerPC support layer has been actively removed then no command will make them "just work".  You need to either downgrade to a previous version of the OS or upgrade the app.

Comment: @AimadMajdou - The command you found only works on OS X 10.6

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can run ppc applications on the newer versions of OS X is if you install them on an old version of OS X that supports PowerPC applications, patch the application to work with intel macs, and then upgrade the OS, in that order. Unfortunately, patches don't always exist for PPC applications. In that case, you're probably out of luck.